# overwrite tt_content column only for custom content element

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-7.x

I have created a custom content element without extending the tt_content columns because the existing fields in the database are sufficient for what I need.

I am using "header", "header_link" and "image" but I need the "image" column to have a different TCA configuration when it's used in my custom content element.

I can change the configuration globally:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['image']['config']['maxitems'] = 1;
```

but that's not what I want.

Something like

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['my_custom_element']['columns']['image']['config']['maxitems'] = 1;
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['my_custom_element']['image']['config']['maxitems'] = 1;
```

isn't working.

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I want? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented yet but the following code works in TYPO3 7.3

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_custom_element']['columnsOverrides'] = array(
  'image' => array(
    'config' => array(
      'maxitems' => 1
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

@dmnkhhn is right. below is your solution if your TYPO3 CMS version is newer or equal to TYPO3 CMS 7.3

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$myCType]['columnsOverrides']['images']['config']['maxitems'] = 1;
```

> Note that you have to configure you new plugin type as a `ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT` for this to work.

## Example

Take a look at the **Configuration** backend module TCA section and browse to (foldout) tt_content/types/html/columnsOverrides and see how the TYPO3 core handles the override of the bodytext field for the HTML content element.

The **Configuration** backend module is a great tool to learn and understand TCA and other global variables by seeing how other already has done the thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

TCA config of columns is some kind of *final*, that means they are cached once and it's not possible to use different configs for one field depending on any conditions.

The typical solution is adding custom image field ie. `my_image` to the `tt_content` and replacing original `image` field within your CE type only

like (sample):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['Tx_Your_Type']['showitem'] = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['image']['showitem'];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['Tx_Your_Type']['showitem'] = str_replace(',image ,', ',my_image ,', $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['Tx_Your_Type']['showitem']);
```

Comment: I've already tried to create a new column:

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['my_custom_element_image'] = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['image'];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['my_custom_element_image']['config']['maxitems'] = 1;`


… and adding that new column to my CE type but I can't save the element because 'my_custom_element_image' is not a column in the tt_content table.

Comment: Cause you need it also in `ext_tables.sql`, take a look here for some samples: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html ... BTW which version of TYPO3 exactly do you use? add proper tags to your question.

Comment: I am using TYPO3 7.3 – besides that I am fully aware that a custom column requires the column also to be present in the `ext_tables.sql`. A new column was not what I intended to create. I was hoping for a solution that allows me to use the existing columns, just with a new configuration for a custom content element.

Comment: How we can override imagecols items list i need only 2,3,4,6 items.but seems columnoverride does'nt help.it just change list but didn't remove any default items.

Answer (score 0):

Override a field with the  the configuration of another column like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myType']['columnsOverrides']['header']['config'] = 
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header_link']['config'];
```